# failed to integrate some JS code in PHP file

Tags: javascript, php

I have a PHP code, where I need to make some manipulations with JS, and I tried the following

```
<?php
   include './parse.service.php';
   echo putContent();

   $jsScript = "
   <script type='text/javascript'>
   const json = require('./transacitions.json');
   window.onload = modifyData;

   function modifyData() {
       document.getElementById('n_transactions').innerHTML = parseInt(document.getElementById('n_transactions').innerHTML, 10) + json.data.length;
       document.getElementById('total_received').getElementsByTagName('font')[0].getElementsByTagName('span')[0].innerHTML = `${this.totalReceived(convertToFloat(document.getElementById('total_received').getElementsByTagName('font')[0].getElementsByTagName('span')[0].innerHTML))} BTC`;
       document.getElementById('final_balance').getElementsByTagName('font')[0].getElementsByTagName('span')[0].innerHTML = `${this.finalBalance(convertToFloat(document.getElementById('final_balance').getElementsByTagName('font')[0].getElementsByTagName('span')[0].innerHTML))} BTC`;
   }

   function convertToFloat(element) {
       var numb = element.match(/[+-]?\d+(\.\d+)?/g);
       numb = numb.join(\"\");
       return (parseFloat(numb, 10));
   }

   function totalReceived(quantity) {
       json.data.forEach(element => {
           if (element.finalSum > 0) {
               quantity += element.finalSum;
           };
       });
       return quantity;
   };


   function finalBalance(quantity) {
       json.data.forEach(element => {
           quantity += element.finalSum;
       });
       return quantity;
   };
   </script>";
   echo $jsScript;
?>
```

And when I echo the created "script", i get the message similar to this  `Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function totalReceived()` how shall I modify the code, in sucha a way that JS will integrate normally in my PHP script.

Comment: What line does that error message refer to? Probably `this.totalReceived`? Why `this`? None of this is an object method, so no `this` needed.

Comment: Please add full code and exact where error is generated

Comment: I advice you to create a js file and include that file.
That being said the problem probably arrives because you need to escape charaters

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`$` has special meaning inside PHP strings delimited with `"` characters, so `${this.totalReceived` is causing the PHP engine to try to find an execute a function called `totalReceived`.

There's no apparent reason to use a PHP string here anyway. Just exit PHP mode and just output the code directly.

```
<?php
    include './parse.service.php';
    echo putContent();
?>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
    const json = require('./transacitions.json');
    window.onload = modifyData;

    // etc etc 
    </script>
```

Better yet. Move the JS to a separate file and include it with `<script src>`.

Comment: I thought about the idea with `<script src>` but the problem is that I have there a `<base>` tag too, which messes my src...